# Left Outer join with condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to merge two data frames (how=left) but not only on an index but only on a condition.

E.g assume two data frame

```
      C1 C2 
  A = I  3  
      K  2  
      L  5

      C1 C2 C3
  B = I  5  T
      I  0  U
      K  1  X     
      L  7  Z
```

Now I would like to left outer join table A with B using index C1 under the condition that A.C2 > B.C2. That is, the final result should look like

```
       A.C1  A.C2 B.C2 B.C3
A<-B = I        1    0    U
       K        2    1    X
       L        5    Null Null
```

P.S.: If you want to test it your self:

```
import pandas as pd

df_A = pd.DataFrame([], columns={'C 1', 'C2'})
df_A['C 1'] = ['I', 'K', 'L']
df_A['C2'] = [3, 2, 5]

df_B = pd.DataFrame([], columns={'C1', 'C2', 'C3'})
df_B['C1'] = ['I', 'I', 'K', 'L']
df_B['C2'] = [5, 0, 2, 7]
df_B['C3'] = ['T', 'U', 'X', 'Z']
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: the link should help you ! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549492/joining-two-pandas-dataframes-based-on-multiple-conditions

Comment: @ShivaPrakash: No there is no conditional merge mentioned in your suggested link

Comment: Take a look at this [Pandas: Join dataframe with condition
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080248/pandas-join-dataframe-with-condition).

Comment: Some other relevant links: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas, (2) https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7480.

Comment: @CypherX: In your first link, the rows are completely discarded after the merge. I want to merge only parts from table B. That makes a difference

Comment: @LazlooXp These links are only there for you to get some guidance/ideas. In most cases they will not give you an exact solution. What you want is `conditional merge in pandas dataframes`.

Comment: @LazlooXp Why does your expected output have `A.C2 = [1, 2]` instead of `[3, 2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one non-pandas-native solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

df_A = pd.DataFrame([], columns={'C1', 'C2'})
df_A['C1'] = ['I', 'K', 'L']
df_A['C2'] = [3, 2, 5]
cols = df_A.columns
cols = cols.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'))
df_A.columns = cols

df_B = pd.DataFrame([], columns={'C1', 'C2', 'C3'})
df_B['C1'] = ['I', 'I', 'K', 'L']
df_B['C2'] = [5, 0, 2, 7]
df_B['C3'] = ['T', 'U', 'X', 'Z']


# df_merge = pd.merge(left=df_A, right=df_B, how='left', on='C1')

df_sql = pysqldf("""
select *
from df_A t_1
left join df_B t_2 on t_1.C1 = t_2.C1 and t_1.C2 >= t_2.C2
;
""")
```

However, for big tables, pandasql turns out to be less performant.

Output:

```
   C2 C1    C3   C2    C1
0   3  I     U  0.0     I
1   2  K     X  2.0     K
2   5  L  None  NaN  None
```

Comment: This gives me an error. Drop the comma at the end of `select t_1.C1, t_1.C2,` to avoid it.

Comment: Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution would be to simply join on the C1 column and then put NULL or NaN into C3 for all the rows where C2_1 > C2_2.

Comment: I expand the description of the problem. As you can see now, just replacing values with does unfortunately not help as a further problem is the duplication of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Method: direct SQL query into pandas using `pandasql` library. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865608/executing-an-sql-query-over-a-pandas-dataset/45866311)

```py
import pandas as pd

df_A = pd.DataFrame([], columns={'C1', 'C2'})
df_A['C1'] = ['I', 'K']
df_A['C2'] = [3, 2]

df_B = pd.DataFrame([], columns={'C1', 'C2', 'C3'})
df_B['C1'] = ['I', 'I', 'K']
df_B['C2'] = [5, 0, 2]
df_B['C3'] = ['T', 'U', 'X']
```

It appears to me that the conditions that you specified for doing the outer join on (A.C1 = B.C1) does not produce the expected result. I needed to do `GROUP BY A.C1` in order to drop duplicate rows having same values in A.C1 after the join.

```py
import pandasql as ps

q = """
SELECT A.C1 as 'A.C1', 
       A.C2 as 'A.C2', 
       B.C2 as 'B.C2', 
       B.C3 as 'B.C3' 
    FROM df_A AS A    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN df_B AS B 
    --ON A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 = B.C2
    WHERE A.C2 > B.C2
    GROUP BY A.C1
"""
print(ps.sqldf(q, locals()))
```

#### Output

```
  A.C1  A.C2  B.C2 B.C3
0    I     3     2    X
1    K     2     0    U
```

### Other References

1. https://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-outer-join/
2. [Executing an SQL query over a pandas dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865608/executing-an-sql-query-over-a-pandas-dataset/45866311)
3. [How to do a conditional join in python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas)
4. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7480
5. https://medium.com/jbennetcodes/how-to-rewrite-your-sql-queries-in-pandas-and-more-149d341fc53e

Comment: What is still missing is the behavior when there is no match in table B (either because C1 is not matching or the condition on C2 is not fulfilled). In these cases, the should not be deleted but the right side should be filled with nulls. I will adapt the description accordingly later. THX for now