# How to merge two dataframes based on OR condition on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Elaborating from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53549492/4146521), I am trying to match two Pandas dataframes.

The matching condition is:

```
(left['to_match'] == right['first']) | (left['to_match'] == right['second'])
```

or, in words, the column to match in the left dataframe should be equal to either first or second column in the right dataframe - thus the OR condition.

I can make a workaround using `pd.merge` and inputting lists such as

```
left.merge(right, left_on=['to_match', 'to_match'], right_on=['first', 'second'])
```

but this, in turn, gives me only the AND condition result *when both columns match*. That is, the two columns in `right` have the same value.

This is an example of input data

left

```
    to_match
0   TCNU4843483
1   MA18219
2   MA81192
3   MFREIGHT
```

right

```
    first       second
0   ASDREF      TCNU4843483
1   MA18219     Null
2   Null        Null
3   HROB789     NESU6748392
```

and this of the expected output

```
    to_match          first       second
0   TCNU4843483       ASDREF      TCNU4843483   
1   MA18219           MA18219     Null
2   MA81192           Null        Null
3   MFREIGHT          Null        Null
4   Null              HROB789     NESU6748392
```

Any idea about whether Pandas support this, or I have to write my own function?

Comment: kindly share input data with expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy edited as requested

Comment: i dont think u can pull this off in Pandas. SQL

Comment: I don't understand how rows 2 through 4 make it into the expected resultset since they're not matching on either column...

Comment: @mechanical_meat true that, I was thinking perhaps it could be possible with an outer join.

Comment: @sammywemmy can one do SQL in Pandas? I have a .xlsx file. I ended up for now using the `query` method and then either updating the row when matching or appending a new one.

Comment: SQLite can help. And is usually bundled with python installation. If ur method works no biggie. I feel sql is optimised for ur use case. U can connect to and from sql with pandas

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, what you can do is create a separate merge column for the right, then use it as the `right_on`.

(I'm assuming "Null" represents missing values.)

```
left_on = 'to_match'
right_on_either = ['first', 'second']

# Build up right merger column iteratively.
right_merger = pd.Series(index=right.index)
for col in right_on_either:
    right_merger[right[col] == left[left_on]] = right[col]
right_merger
```

```
0    TCNU4843483
1        MA18219
2            NaN
3            NaN
dtype: object
```

```
left.merge(right, how='outer', left_on='to_match', right_on=right_merger)
```

```
      to_match    first       second
0  TCNU4843483   ASDREF  TCNU4843483
1      MA18219  MA18219          NaN
2      MA81192      NaN          NaN
3     MFREIGHT      NaN          NaN
4          NaN      NaN          NaN
5          NaN  HROB789  NESU6748392
```

The row of all NaNs is supposed to be there since there's no match for row `2` of `right`. If you want to remove it, just `.dropna(how='all')`. If you had lots of NaNs so wanted to keep the result size down, you could drop them beforehand:

```
right = right.dropna(how='all')
...
    right_merger[right[col] == left.loc[right.index, left_on]] = right[col]
```

Answer (score -1):

No SQL is not the best tool for the job. SQL is good to extract data, period!

I believe that your OR condition is not working because you are closing the operation with the ()

try:

```
(left['to_match'] == right['first'] | left['to_match'] == right['second'])
```

Comment: The parentheses are because of [operator precedence](//docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Bitwise operations (i.e. `|`) are more tightly binding than comparison operations (i.e. `==`).